# How do you change what gets displayed on a front-end (Angular) view based on properties in your JWT token?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, token, passport.js, jwt

I'm pretty new to working with tokens. Just started learning yesterday.

I have an Express backend API. I understand that the token prevents anyone from getting access to data on any given API endpoint/json data...But how can I READ/decrypt the JWT when it's on the angular side?

I.E., Okay, I know that this user is logged in and can therefore view this page, however, this particular user is the CREATOR of this event. Therefore, on this event's show page, users who have been invited are allowed to view it, and so is the event creator, but only the event creator will see a button that when clicked, does a delete request to the event. The other users will not see this button.

The only way I see this being possible is that the JWT containing the user object can be decoded on the front/end, then I have access to variables with the decoded JWT properties. I.E., username and userID. That way, on the view page being rendered in Angular, I can code logic such as:
```

```
if (decodedJWT.user.username === event.creator.username) {
 DO SOMETHING HERE LIKE DISPLAY A CERTAIN BUTTON
}
```

```

Thanks.

Comment: decrypting the token client side defeats the whole purpose of using jwt in the first place. Do it server side and pass whatever insensitive data is needed from there

Comment: JWT can be confusing, but charlieftl is correct. You don't ever want to decode the token client-side. Re-read this if you haven't already to get a better understanding: https://jwt.io/introduction/

Comment: To add to my comment, the JWT *can't* be decoded without the secret key.

Comment: What about an angular service like JWT-angular, which Auth0 uses, and gives you the ability to decrypt it client side? Just curious about that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an API point in your nodeJS backend that will return the user details if he is logged in:

```
app.use('/userinfo', expressJwt({secret: secret}));
```

Here you make sure `/userinfo` is protected by JWT and your secret phrase.

Then the route corresponding to this API returns user info:

```
router.get('/get', function (request, response) {
  response.json({
    id: request.user.id,
    name: request.user.nom,
    email: request.user.email,
    role: request.user.role
  });
});
```

The full API is located at `/userinfo/get` and is secured by the JWT token.

In angularJS you just need to make a request to that API using simple `$http.get('/userinfo/get')` which will return a user object or an error from the server if not logged in.

Of course you need to [pass the token to all your $http requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39227966/angular-js-add-request-parameter-on-every-http-request-http/39229026#39229026).

Comment: Awesome description and clearly answers the question. Basically, I would set up the server to respond with the json user object. However, this user object data would only be sent when a user browses to the /userinfo/get route. Meaning in Angular, by default, only in the controller where I do a $http.get request to that route will I have that data. How would you suggest having that user json object data 'persist' throughout my entire front end Angular session?

I.E. if I'm on an event page (/events/8)...I want to do a conditional where if (event.creator.id === user.id) { do stuff }

Comment: ^ I believe I just answered my question on my comment above after thinking about it. If there is an easier way please share for the community. My idea is this: In Angular, simply setup a userObjectCheck factory, which does a requestt to that protected '/userinfo/get' route, and returns the object if it exists (if user is logged in, the angular interceptor will send the token automatically each request, allowing the factory to access the factory's endpoint). Now, in any controller where I need that user, I will just set a variable to equal the return value of the factory and it all works out.

Comment: @Tyler Yes, a factory/service is the way to go.